# How to take IP address as input

Tags: perl, xpath, perl-module, xpath-2.0

How to take IP address as input and use it in the Xpath expressions?
When i am using it as a static input like `$iptext = '10.109.25.1';` it is working fine but when i am getting the input from user i am getting error

```
#my $ip = <>;
#my $iptext=$ip.'';
my $query  = "//nodeA/nodeB[nodeC/text() = '$iptext']/../NodeD/Name/text()";
```

Comment: Maybe the `@ARGV` Array is what you are looking for :)

Comment: Never ever say you're getting an error without specifying exactly what the error is.

Comment: Thank you @TLP I would definitely consider that from my next questions.

Comment: Helped me in getting the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume what you are forgetting is that input read with `<>` or `<STDIN>` come with newlines:

```
chomp(my $ip = <>);   # newline removed
```

Documentation for `chomp` [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html).

If you do not remove the newline, your `$query` string will contain that newline, which I assume you pass to Xpath or some such:

```
xpath //nodeA/nodeB[nodeC/text() = '10.109.25.1
']/../NodeD/Name/text()
```

And of course that does not work.